# Did Gus have a family?

Tags: breaking-bad

When Gus invited Walt to his house for dinner, there was a short glimpse of his - probably - living room where we can see a toy car and a toy table. Was Gus’ family ever mentioned in the show? I think there was an implication of Gus being homosexual and the revenge he took on the cartel had also a personal aspect (murder of his partner). I can see a contradiction in this. Maybe he wanted to give Walter an impression that he is also a family man? If so, it would show how sociopathic Gus was.

[image]

Comment: `an implication of Gus being homosexual` Correction: An implication of Gus not being straight. Even if his involvement with Max was romantic, that does not exclude Gus from _also_ liking women.